# JTabbedPane Component takes up entire window

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm new to Java and the entire swing development.  I'm working on a Window with three tabs and adding each component to those tabs.  I started by adding a textfield to the 3rd tab, but it's taking up the entire tab.  I'm sure if I add other components it will make room, but isn't there a way to make it so it doesn't initially take up the entire Tabbed Pane?

```
package literature.windows;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

JPanel storiesPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel plotPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel charactersPanel = new JPanel();

JTextField addCharacterTextField = new JTextField("Enter Character's Name", 25);

public MainWindow() {

    setSize(800, 600);

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    tabs.addTab("Stories", storiesPanel);
    tabs.addTab("Plot", plotPanel);
    tabs.addTab("Characters", charactersPanel);
    add(tabs);

    tabs.setTabComponentAt(2, addCharacterTextField);

    setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently setting the entire tab component for that tab. Instead you need to add the `JTextField` to the container/panel for that tab. Replace

```
tabs.setTabComponentAt(2, addCharacterTextField);
```

with

```
charactersPanel.add(addCharacterTextField);
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't beleive I over looked that.